# String interpolation parsing not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, string-interpolation

I have the following simple, fresh, single-view project in Xcode 10 with Swift 4.2

I introduced a typo in the string interpolation of the first string, but the compiler does not complain and the code runs.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let number: Int = 50
        var string = "\(number.numberString, withValue: false) lbs"
        print(string)
        string = "\(number.numberString(withValue: false)) lbs"
        print(string)
    }
}
extension Int {
    func numberString(withValue value: Bool) -> String {
        if value == true {
            return "value"
        } else {
            return String(self)
        }
    }
}
```

the printout is:

```
((Function), withValue: false) lbs
50 lbs
```

It is taking the first parameter as "(Function)", and reporting the rest of text inside the parenthesis as part of the text, but the editor doesn't show it as a text.
Is there something I don't understand in the string interpolation syntax? or is this a complier issue/bug?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's displaying exactly what you're requesting. You're evaluating:

`(number.numberString, withValue: false)`

This is a tuple with an unlabeled function value and a labeled boolean value. The description of that tuple would be:

`((Function), withValue: false)`

Comment: Upsss.... @Rob Napier. I did not consider the Tuple option.   Also, I did not know that you could evaluate a function without the parenthesis (I assumed that you would have to do something like: number.numberString() and that the return value is what is being evaluated.....   I learned something.   Thx a lot... ...   enrique